# Is CASE possible in concatenating strings in Informix SQL dialect?

Tags: sql, informix

I want to make report of types used in Informix database. Decoding of `datetime` is a little fancy according to documentation (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_027.htm )

Now I have such SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
CASE MOD(coltype, 256)
    WHEN  0 THEN 'char'
    WHEN  1 THEN 'smallint'
    WHEN  2 THEN 'integer'
    WHEN  3 THEN 'float'
    WHEN  4 THEN 'smallfloat'
    WHEN  5 THEN 'decimal(' || (collength / 256)::int || ', ' || mod(collength, 256) || ')'
    WHEN  6 THEN 'serial'
    WHEN  7 THEN 'date'
    WHEN  8 THEN 'money(' || (collength / 256)::int || ', ' || mod(collength, 256) || ')'
    WHEN  9 THEN 'null'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'datetime '  || substr(hex(collength), -2, 1) || ' to ' || substr(hex(collength), -1, 1)
    WHEN 11 THEN 'byte'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'text'
    WHEN 13 THEN 'varchar'
    WHEN 14 THEN 'interval'
    WHEN 15 THEN 'nchar'
    WHEN 16 THEN 'nvarchar'
    WHEN 17 THEN 'int8'
    WHEN 18 THEN 'serial8'
    WHEN 19 THEN 'set'
    WHEN 20 THEN 'multiset'
    WHEN 21 THEN 'list'
    WHEN 22 THEN 'row (unnamed)'
    WHEN 23 THEN 'collection'
    WHEN 40 THEN 'lvarchar fixed-length opaque types'
    WHEN 41 THEN 'blob, boolean, clob variable-length opaque types'
    WHEN 43 THEN 'lvarchar (client-side only)'
    WHEN 45 THEN 'boolean'
    WHEN 52 THEN 'bigint'
    WHEN 53 THEN 'bigserial'
    WHEN 2061 THEN 'idssecuritylabel'
    WHEN 4118 THEN 'row (named)'
    ELSE '???'
END CASE
FROM syscolumns, systables
WHERE tabtype='T'
AND systables.tabid >= 100
AND tabname[1] <> '_'
AND syscolumns.tabid = systables.tabid
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2;
```

And in reports I see:

```
datetime 0 to 4
```

How can I replace this `0` to `year` and `4` to `day` using SQL only? I tried to add `CASE` in string concatenating in `CASE` just like:

```
...
WHEN 10 THEN 'datetime '  || substr(hex(collength), -2, 1) || ' to ' || case substr(hex(collength), -1, 1) when '4' then 'day' else '?' end case
...
```

but I got syntax error.

Is it possible in just SQL?

Comment: You are already inside a case expression... and you expect to start another one? You need to alter the **when** condition to include **when 10 and ...**

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for both variants of a CASE statement is:

```
CASE … END
```

and not

```
CASE … END CASE
```

See [CASE expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1442.htm).

Thus, it's possible that:

```
WHEN 10 THEN 'datetime ' || SUBSTR(HEX(collength), -2, 1) || ' to ' ||
             CASE SUBSTR(HEX(collength), -1, 1) WHEN '4' THEN 'day' ELSE '?' END
```

would work.  It should not generate a syntax error from the same cause, at least.

---

I regard that SQL as largely unmaintainable.  It certainly should not be created more than once.  You'd probably do better to write it in a stored procedure.

You should be able to find such stored procedures either already in Informix (`ifx_param_types` and related functions; you can find their definitions in the `.sql` files in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc` — but a number of them invoke C UDRs that are provided with the system), or in tools on the International Informix User Group ([IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/)) web site.  For example, my SQLCMD has 'ESQL/C' code (really C code using some ESQL/C headers) that does the job — `esqltype.ec` is the file for that.